# Code highlighted as syntax error. Why?

Tags: java

I'm new to java and I'm trying to write this code but somehow it sees it as an error when using my variables. which has been declared ofc.

```
import java.io.*;

public class FileRead {
     public void readCountries(String file){
         try{
             ObjectInputStream inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("countries"));
             Object obj = null;
             while ((obj = inputStream.readObject()) != null) {
                 if (obj instanceof Country) {
                     System.out.println(((Country)obj).toString());
                 }
             }
         } catch (EOFException ex) { //This exception will be caught when EOF is reached
                System.out.println("End of file reached.");
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                //Close the ObjectInputStream
                try {
                    if (inputStream != null) { //////////ERROR: inputStream cannot be resolved to a variable
                        inputStream.close(); //////////// Same here
                    }
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move your inputStream declaration outside try block. If you define inside try, it is not visible outside the `try` block.

```
    ObjectInputStream inputStream = null;
    try{
     inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new  FileInputStream("countries"));
     ........
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You define `inputStream` *inside* the scope of the `try` block, and hence cannot access it outside.

You can resolve this by doing something like,

```
ObjectInputStream inputStream = null;
try{
    inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("countries"));
    ...
}
```

i.e. defining the variable *outside* of the `try`-block and assigning it within. This way, you can access `inputStream` outside of the `try`-block.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple, you are trying to access a variable outside of the scope where it was declared. Here is a simplified example of your problem:

```
try {
    int i = 0;
} catch(Exception e) {
    //...
}

++i;
```

You see? Once the variable escapes the braces where it was declared, it's lost. In your example:

```
try{
     ObjectInputStream inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("countries"));
     //...
 } finally {
    if (inputStream != null) { //////////ERROR: inputStream cannot be resolved to a variable
        inputStream.close(); //////////// Same here
    }
}
```

just drag `inputStream` outside:

```
ObjectInputStream inputStream = null;
try{
     inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("countries"));
     //...
 } finally {
    if (inputStream != null) {
        inputStream.close();
    }
}
```

Or even better use **try-with-resources** (hey, Java 7 is no longer new and fresh!)

```
try(ObjectInputStream inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("countries")) {
    //...
}
```

No `finally`, `close()`, etc. needed.

Answer (score 1):

It's a problem of variable scope.

Your `inputStream` variable belongs to `try` block that doesn't encompass the same scope as the `catch` or `finally` block causing `inputStream` to be undeclared in the `catch` or `finally` block. Thus, this variable is unknown within the `catch` block, explaining your "**variable may not be initialized**" shown by your IDE.

Simply, initializes your variable to `null` outside the first `try`/`catch` as follows:

```
ObjectInputStream inputStream = null;
try{
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable is declared inside the `try { ... }` block, so its scope and visibility is restricted to it. You can't use it outside.

You can declare it outside the block:

```
ObjectInputStream inputStream = null;
try{
         inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("countries"));
    //...    
 } catch (EOFException ex) { //This exception will be caught when EOF is reached
    //...      
 } finally {
            //Close the ObjectInputStream
            try {
                if (inputStream != null) { //////////ERROR: inputStream cannot be resolved to a variable
                    inputStream.close(); //////////// Same here
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

inputstream does not exist outside the {} of your try/catch